# How to check for strings in a panel?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a string checker which should check for a string on a website.
I'm using a panel instead of a web browser because I merged chromium with CefSharp into it.

Now I can't figure out how to check for a string in the panel.

I tried creating a different type of variable, but the variable comes from a file. 
I also tried for normal text without variables.

Both didn't work.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim site As String = File.ReadAllText("webstore.shd")
    Dim id As String = File.ReadAllText("ID.shd")
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(site) With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)

    If Panel1.Contains(id) Then
    ' I am stuck right here.
    msgbox("Succes")
    Else
    msgbox("Nope")
    End If

End Sub
```

I expected that the program would search for the variable in the panel, but it wouldn't do that.

Comment: The Panel doesn't know anything about your file. It simply works as just a container for your browser (or any other controls).

Comment: How through, I already dimmed id as a string at the top of the sub.

Comment: Yes, but the panel does not _contain_ that Id; it contains _the browser control_ and only because you added it to the panel (i.e., `Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)`). A panel is just a container _for controls_; nothing else. I suppose you're trying to find an element by Id in the loaded webpage? If so, you'll need to search for it _in the browser_, not the panel. I haven't used CefSharp before, but with a quick search, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50688705/4934172) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37712962/4934172); they could be useful.