# How can I read canvas with id

Tags: javascript, windows, vb.net

I am using CefSharp (Chrome browser for .NET projects) and I want to read a canvas HTML tag with id.

This tag has a base64 image and refreshes in 100 milliseconds.

I want to read the canvas image and show it on picture box.

This tag doesn't have any option to read base64:

```html
<div id="grapher" class="grapher">
    <canvas id="grapher" width="560" height="451" style="width: 560px; height: 451px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

Comment: no i want read canvas by id with vb.net or c#

Comment: How about if you combine it with [CefSharp - Get Value of HTML Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712962/cefsharp-get-value-of-html-element)?

Comment: for doing this i must execute a javascript code(for get output canvas image) then show that on picturebox(in c# or vb.net)
but i dont have that js code for read that

Comment: Please see the first post I linked to.